# discord.js bot: i cant execute functions on userdata from a json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a discord bot and i made some achievements you can get. There is a json file where all the data gets stored. So a json string looks like this:

```
"784095768305729566": {
    "coins": 14598,
    "achievements": {
      "taking_inventory": true
    }
  },
```

Now i want to make a command where you can see all your achievements and all the achievements you dont have. So this is my script:

```
onst discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client({intents:["GUILDS","GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

const fs = require("fs");
var read_data = fs.readFileSync("./userdata.json");
var datafile = JSON.parse(read_data);

client.on("message", message => {
  var msg_value = message.content.toLowerCase();
  var username = message.author.username;
  var id = message.author.id;
if(message.content.includes("!squid ac")){
    let mentioned_user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.member.user;
    let mentioned_user_id = mentioned_user.id;
    if(!datafile[mentioned_user_id]){
      datafile[mentioned_user_id] = {coins: 0, achievements: {taking_inventory: false}};
      fs.writeFileSync("./userdata.json", JSON.stringify(datafile, null, 2));
      let achievements = String(datafile[mentioned_user_id].achievements);
      message.channel.send(`Achievements from <@${mentioned_user_id}>: ${achievements}`);
    }
    else{
      let achievements = datafile[mentioned_user_id].achievements.substring(0, 1);
      message.channel.send(`Achievements from <@${mentioned_user_id}>: ${achievements}`)
      console.log(achievements)
    }
    proof_achievement_inventory();
  }

  function proof_achievement_inventory(){ ... }
```

I tried making a foreach method for every achievement substring but it always says this Error:

```
TypeError: datafile[mentioned_user_id].achievements.substring is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\index.js:104:67)
    at Client.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:34:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:478:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:317:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1169:20)
```

Comment: What do you expect `achievements.substring(0, 1)` returns? `achievements` is an object so it won't have a `substring` method.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i was originally writing achievements.forEach(...) and it said the same error.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros what i want to do is making an embed and adding a text field for each achievement substring.